# What is the use of the DMA controller in a processor?

Tags: performance, memory-management, cpu-architecture, dma

DMA controllers are present on disks, networking devices. So they can transfer data to main memory directly. Then what is use of the dma controller inside processor chip ?Also i would like to know, if there are different buses (i2c, pci, spi) outside of processor chip and only one bus (AXI) inside processor. how does this work?(shouldn’t it result in some bottleneck)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **on-chip DMA** can take the task of copying data from devices to memory and viceversa **for simple devices that cannot implement a DMA of their own**. I can think that such devices can be a mouse, a keyboard, a soundcard, a bluetooth device, etc. These devices have simple logic and their requests are multiplexed and sent to a single general purpose DMA on the chip.

Peripherals with high bandwidths like **GPU cards, Network Adapters, Hard Disks implement their own DMA** that communicates with the chip's bus in order to initiate uploads and downloads to the system's memory.

> if there are different buses (i2c, pci, spi) outside of processor chip
>   and only one bus (AXI) inside processor. how does this work?(shouldn’t
>   it result in some bottleneck)

That's actually simple. The **on-chip internal AXI bus is much faster** - running at a much higher frequency (*equal or in the same range to the CPU's frequency*) (has a much higher bandwidth) than all the aggregated bandwidths of i2c+pci+spi. Of course multiple hardware elements compete on the AXI bus but usually you have priorities implemented and different optimization techniques.

Comment: I assumed Disk controller is same as DMA controller. So the Disk controllers job is just to read/write from disk and dump it in buffer is it?(This functionality seems to be similar to DMA controller)

Answer (score -1):

**From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_memory_access)**:

> Direct memory access (DMA) is a feature of computerized systems that allows certain hardware subsystems to access main system memory independently of the central processing unit (CPU). [...] A DMA controller can generate memory addresses and initiate memory read or write cycles. It contains several processor registers that can be written and read by the CPU. These include a memory address register, a byte count register, and one or more control registers.

Comment: oh thank you PARK YOUNG-BAE!! my mistake...'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_memory_access'

Comment: I am asking "why inside the processor chip" since it is already present on disks. And why will the external io device transfer data to main mem via CPU chip .

Comment: @MayurGupta that does not really answer the question. You need to understand the answer yourself at first and then make sure to explain to the OP.

Comment: Answers on Stack overflow should be more than just copy-paste info!